# Inclusion of transitive dependency jars using copy-dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. I have a utility project that contains common classes etc., and I need to reference that `jar` in 2 of my other projects. Lets say the common `jar` is `common.jar`, and the other project I use it in is `service1`. I define a local repo folder in `service1`, include the `common.jar` there and define it as a dependency in `service1`'s `pom.xml`.
2. Compile time works fine, I am also able to run this from within Eclipse.
3. Now I want to generate a `service1.jar` and have all its dependencies copied to the `lib` folder so that I can just run it as `java -jar service.jar` and have the `lib` folder included in the classpath. I am able to do this using the `copy-dependencies` plugin.

   However, this plugin only copies the direct dependencies of `service1` and does not copy the `jar`s that are mentioned in the `pom.xml` of `common` project.

However, I do need those `common` project's dependency `jar`s at runtime for successfully running `service1`.

How can I get those `common` project's dependency `jar`s copied over to the final `lib` folder of `service1`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "*I define a local repo folder in `service1`*" – There should be just one local repository folder in conjunction with Maven and it's at `~/.m2/repository` by default. See [Maven / Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) and  [Maven / Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Settings_Details).

This repository acts as your "lib" folder (at compile time) and, if properly declared in the POM(s), Maven takes care of direct and transitive dependencies of your project automagically. See [Maven / Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html).

Hence, there's usually no need to copy dependencies yourself.

So, the best would be to convert your *utility project* to a Maven project and perform a `mvn install` there. Such its artifact – together with the artifact(s) it depends on – is put to the local Maven repository and can be referenced as dependency by the *2 of your other projects* from there.

If this is not possible you can put the utility `jar` to the local repository with the [install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) goal of the [Apache Maven Install Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/):

> - [install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) is mostly used to install an externally created artifact into the local repository, along with its POM. In that case the project information can be taken from an optionally specified pomFile, but can also be given using command line parameters.

Comment: Hi Gerold - Thanks for the answer. However, I am not going with that approach for 2 reasons:1